# How to check XML tag element is not exist in xml file using python?

Tags: python, xml

I would like to get XML tag value
but I have no idea to handle some tag element names that do not exist in the XML files.

here is my XML file

```
<name>Tom</name>
<gender>Male</gender>
<age>20</age>
```

I using the following code to get the XML tag value

```
        tree = ET.parse(data.xml')
        root = tree.getroot()
        for name in root.iter('name'):
            name = name.text
        for age in root.iter('age'):
            age = age.text    
        for gender in root.iter('gender'):
            gender = gender.text
        print(name+age+gender)
```

But how to handle no tag element in XML
such as

```
for address in root.iter('address'): #there are no address tag in xml
address = address.text
```

I get NameError
NameError: name 'address' is not defined

I try to use

```
for address in root.iter('address'):
    if address is not None:
        address = address.text
    else:
        address = "No value"
```

But finally, it still gets NameError: name 'address' is not defined error

anyone can solve it??

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your expected output with and without an `<address>` element?

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```
for address in root.iter('address'):
    address = address.text
if 'address' in locals():
    pass
else:
    address = "No value"
```

Comment: thank you for reply, still get NameError: name 'address' is not defined error